# Перенести только те записи из таблицы_1 в таблицу_2, которых ещё нету в таблице_2 (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Мой запрос берет title, author_id из таблицы supply и author соответственно. Если в таблице book нет записей с такими полями сделать INSERT данных.

```
INSERT INTO book(title, author_id, price, amount) SELECT title,
> author_id, price, amount FROM supply INNER JOIN author ON
> supply.author = author.name_author WHERE title,author_id NOT IN
> (SELECT author_id,title FROM book)
```

Ругается на title в WHERE.
Текст ошибки : "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."
[image: мои таблицы]

Comment: Используйте ROW конструктор: `.. WHERE (title,author_id) NOT IN ..`

Comment: Та же ошибка, и ругается на title в WHERE. При наведении : "В контексте, где ожидается условие, указано выражение не логического типа". В MySQL работет, а в SQL sever не хочет :(

Answer (score 0):

В таких конструкциях, где несколько значений проверяются они тоже должны браться в скобки:

```
WHERE (title,author_id) NOT IN (SELECT author_id,title FROM book)
```